# Объединить по признаку сходства столбцов A и B столбец C в один список

Tags: python, pandas

У меня есть df состоящий из 3х столбцов. Мне нужно объединить по признаку сходства столбцов A и B столбец C в один список. Вот так это должно выглядеть:

Вводные данные:

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': [112, 112, 152, 112, 152, 155],
                   'B': [15,15,17,15,17,18],
                   'C': [1,2,3,4,5,6]})
```

Вывод

```
df2:
A      B     C:
112    15    1,2,4
152    17    3,5
155    18    6
```

Comment: вы хотите список или строку?

Comment: @splash58 Список. Поправил вопрос

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
In [130]: df.groupby(["A", "B"])["C"].apply(list).reset_index()
Out[130]:
     A   B          C
0  112  15  [1, 2, 4]
1  152  17     [3, 5]
2  155  18        [6]
```

если нужно получить строки:

```
In [133]: df.assign(C=df["C"].astype(str)).groupby(["A", "B"])["C"].apply(",".join).reset_index()
Out[133]:
     A   B      C
0  112  15  1,2,4
1  152  17    3,5
2  155  18      6
```